# How do I get an Xbox One controller to work with 16.04 (not Steam)

Tags: 16.04, games

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 and I downloaded a game from GOG called Transistor. I bought a wireless Xbox One controller to play just this kind of game. From what I could find out, wireless isn't supported on Ubuntu for this controller yet so I plugged it in using a [known working] micro-usb > usb adapter.

- I have successfully installed the game. I can play it with my keyboard/mouse. Clicking on the controller icon in the game settings does nothing.
- I have installed "Ubuntu xboxdrv integration" and now have a joystick option in my settings menu. It lists four 360 controllers and none of them respond to input from the controller.
- When I type `lsusb` it lists "Microsoft" as one of the things connected. I disconnected the controller and the entry goes away so I know the controller is being seen by the system. When I plug it in it rumbles for a moment.
- If I press the "X" (connect) button it flashes for almost 30 seconds.

As I understand, wired, even the Xbox One controller, is compatible out of the box with newer versions of Ubuntu. Can anyone tell me what I'm not doing or where to start looking? I'm assuming a newish kernel was installed with the OS.

I typed `lsmod` and there is no `ubuntu-xboxdrv` or `xboxdrv` or even `xpad` in the list. I typed `insmod ubuntu-xboxdrv` into terminal and was told it couldn't load because there's no file or directory. Typing `modprobe ubuntu-xboxdrv` also said it couldn't find it. (I also tried `xboxdrv` for both.)

As far as I can tell, it not being a loaded mod is the number one culprit. How do I see if `ubuntu-xboxdrv` is even the name of the mod? I checked that the install went through by reinstalling. How do I find where it went?

Comment: For those looking for an up to date solution (as of January 2022) see this answer https://superuser.com/a/1653276/518572

Answer (score 18):

**[OP's solution to their own problem](https://askubuntu.com/posts/783587/revisions):**

> First, I read that with kernels later than 4.1* (I checked and I have
>   4.4*), xboxdrv no longer works with, specifically, the xbox one controller.
>
> It seems xpad got love from Steam so it's not as outdated as it used
>   to be. I don't know what it loses to xboxdev but I just want the
>   controller to work.
>
> My controller is the newer firmware version called Covert Forces
>   Edition. Because of its new firmware it needs a patch which I found
>   [here](https://github.com/paroj/xpad).
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install git
> sudo apt-get install dkms
> sudo git clone https://github.com/paroj/xpad.git /usr/src/xpad-0.4
> sudo dkms install -m xpad -v 0.4
> ```
>
> All seemed fine. But I hit `lsmod` and `xpad` still wasn't loaded. To
>   load it I entered:
>
> ```
> sudo modprobe xpad
> ```
>
> This gave me a new error that it could not insert because the required
>   key is not available. This is solved by turning off secure boot in
>   your BIOS.
>
> I put `sudo modprobe xpad` in again and there were no confirmations
>   but no complaints. I looked under `lsmod` and lo and behold, at the
>   top of the list was `xpad`! I'm guessing it's the mod version because
>   now under the joystick menu in settings it comes up as a 5th
>   controller and the damn thing responds. The "X" is lit up and buttons
>   work.

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks a lot for instructions @Zanna !

Comment: Finally... I have been looking for a solution for quite a while now... My controller is a Xbox One S controller and it worked easily on 16.04 but not in 14.04. Using this patch did the trick. The "X" vendor button is finally lit up and not blinking, and the controller works!

Answer (score 8):

1. install `sysfsutils` -  `sudo apt install sysfsutils`
2. open the configuration file with `gksu gedit /etc/sysfs.conf`
3. Add this line in `sysfs.conf` –> `module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm = 1`
4. Save and restart.

Comment: Thank you! Why does this work, why is it needed? Is the ERTM implementation broken in the XBox controller, in the driver or is it something completely different?

Comment: I just tried this on Ubuntu 17.10.  Unfortunately it had no effect:  my Xbox One controllers' lights are blinking, and they are not visible in the Bluetooth settings  panel.

Comment: It bears mentioning that *gksu* is no longer recommended as a means to run desktop applications requiring higher privilege. (it's even been [removed completely in 18.04](https://itsfoss.com/gksu-replacement-ubuntu/)). Please use *$pkexec* instead, as it has been the recommended method for some time now.