# Xbox One controller successfully installed, but game doesn't respond to it

Tags: 16.04, gamepad, xbox-one

After some trial and error I got my Xbox One controller working with a wired micro USB connection, using the advice in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783587/how-do-i-get-an-xbox-one-controller-to-work-with-16-04-not-steam). But the game I'm trying to play, Sonic Lost World on Steam running under Wine, doesn't respond to the controller inputs, and doesn't have any settings for choosing a controller or keyboard. The JSCtl GUI verifies that the computer can detect my controller inputs.

When I briefly succeeded in making a wireless connection to the controller, via [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/5ezvt7/connecting_xbox_one_bt_controller_ubuntu_1604/), my mouse moved whenever I moved the joystick. That isn't happening in this wired connection. Do I need to re-route mouse input to /dev/input/js4 or something?

I'm using Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and my kernel version is 4.8.0-32-generic.

Comment: I wonder if you could use xev to discover the keycodes for the controller, and then map them with the keyboard shortcuts applet?

Comment: This article suggest that you might try using xboxdrv instead of xpad: https://www.maketecheasier.com/set-up-xbox-one-controller-ubuntu/ Don't know if that will solve the issues with your specific game, but probably couldn't hurt to try it.

Comment: Here is my explanation how to fix: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438422/22-04-the-xbox-controller-of-wine-has-a-mistake-how-to-fix/