# How to connect XBOX 360 Wireless on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, games, joystick

I'm asking this because of my paranoia. I already know about this question: [How do I get an XBOX 360 controller working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165210/how-do-i-get-an-xbox-360-controller-working), but I want someone to confirm that this is working on 16.04 too.

I want to buy 2 Xbox 360 Controllers, and they come with a Wireless adapter from a site like eBay. The problem is that I want to use them on my Ubuntu 16.04 Laptop, and I want to be sure that this configuration will work. What do I need to install and do?

Comment: *sticsk:* Do you have any reason to think it won't work for you on 16.04? I ask as [this answer explicitly supports 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/448217). @MichaelBay & reviewers: This is asking how to find out if a specific peripheral device will work, *not* for what device to use. Numerous questions on this site are about *how* to get particular hardware working. Such questions differ from asking *if* the specific hardware can work at all only by being *broader*, and they're still on topic and not too broad. This seems like a duplicate though, in that one of the answers there does cover it.

Comment: See also [How do I get an Xbox One controller to work with 16.04 (not Steam)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/783587/how-do-i-get-an-xbox-one-controller-to-work-with-16-04-not-steam), if [Rael Gugelmin Cunha's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/448217/22949) to [How do I get an XBOX 360 controller working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165210/how-do-i-get-an-xbox-360-controller-working) is not sufficient. (Btw, the banner here says the question was closed as off-topic, but 2/5 of us voted to make it a duplicate.)

Comment: @EliahKagan No worries, It's quite likely that https://askubuntu.com/questions/165210/how-do-i-get-an-xbox-360-controller-working/448217#448217 will solve the problem for the OP. It's hard to imagine 17 upvotes on an answer that doesn't work. ;-)