# ubuntu 18.04 LTS bluetooth 'on' button not working

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

I try to connect Xbox one via Bluetooth adapter on my PC but before I get any problems (as usual) with the connection I have problems with even enabling Bluetooth: the button is 'off' and locked to change it.
[image: sorry for Russian]

I tried a lot. First of all I get xpadneo, done this:

```
sudo apt install sysfsutils
sudo nano /etc/sysfs.conf
```

Placed the following at the end of the file. "/module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm=1"

Tried solution here: [ubuntu 18.04 LTS bluetooth [0cf3:3004] discovery not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032417/ubuntu-18.04-lts-bluetooth-0cf33004-discovery-not-working)

Tried `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`

Install bluez and some other stuff. Nothing helps.

bluetoothctl - not responding

```
pruntoff@samus:~$ bluetoothctl
Waiting to connect to bluetoothd...
```

Some commands:

```
pruntoff@samus:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 045e:02fe Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1a81:1004 Holtek Semiconductor, Inc. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


pruntoff@samus:~$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[   93.896221] audit: type=1107 audit(1572797372.145:56): pid=803 uid=106 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=2034 label="snap.chromium.chromium"
```

rfkill is installed but returns nothing.

I'm 64bit PC Intel® Core™ i5-4460 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4 
GNOME 3.28.2

```
pruntoff@samus:~$ uname -r
4.15.0-66-generic
```

Thanks in advance!

UPD:
Some more commands:

```
pruntoff@samus:~$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
```

**UPD2:** Yep, it is external, just dongle.
Requested outputs:

```
pruntoff@samus:~$ dmesg | tail
[ 2493.764744] usb 3-4: Product: XBOX ACC
[ 2493.764747] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: Microsoft Inc.
[ 2493.764750] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 140770
[ 2501.628448] usb 3-4: USB disconnect, device number 5
[ 2519.475760] usb 3-4: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[ 2519.625396] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=02fe
[ 2519.625401] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2519.625404] usb 3-4: Product: XBOX ACC
[ 2519.625407] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: Microsoft Inc.
[ 2519.625409] usb 3-4: SerialNumber: 140770
```

Seem it do not find drivers...

```
pruntoff@samus:~$ usb-devices
    ...
    T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  6 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
    D:  Ver= 2.01 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
    P:  Vendor=045e ProdID=02fe Rev=01.00
    S:  Manufacturer=Microsoft Inc.
    S:  Product=XBOX ACC
    S:  SerialNumber=140770
    C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=500mA
    I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 8 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=(none)
    ...
```

Comment: Is it an external USB BT adapter?

Comment: If it is an external dongle, then insert it and post output of `dmesg | tail` right after you insert it. It seems that it is not properly recognized by the kernel.

Comment: Also please add output of `usb-devices` command to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes it is dongle. Seems Ubuntu does not see any drivers. But I have any: xpad, xboxdrv, xpadneo ...

Comment: I don't know what is XBOX ACC. Is it a BT dongle? Or you have another dongle?

Comment: @Pilot6 It is xbox wireless adapter referenced to some tutorials it seems to be Bluetooth adapter.  Do not know is it dongle? It should appear in bluetooth settings and pair to controller.

Comment: I don't think it is a BT adapter.

Comment: Search google by "Ubuntu XBOX ACC"

Comment: @Pilot6 used to it. No solutions though. But thanks for your help and time

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/783587/how-do-i-get-an-xbox-one-controller-to-work-with-16-04-not-steam

Comment: I've tried this it was no help.

Answer (score 0):

When you use BlueZ you must use its controls and settings, not the built in ones.

Comment: thanks a lot. I can figure out how to start BlueZ controls and it looks like it does not see any adapters as well.

Comment: Hmm. You might need to disable ``bluetoothd`` or something as well, in case it's claiming the hardware and BlueZ therefore can't "see" the adaptor. I'm afraid that I sold the 1 laptop on which I needed to use BlueZ, so I can't test this easily.

Comment: You also might need some GNOME extension to show "legacy" icons, such as "Tray Icons", to get the BlueZ icon to show. I only used it on Unity, not GNOME 3, as I do not like or use GNOME 3.